# Syntax error on simple IF.

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Before you ask, I did look at other answers and questions they all seem to be the same and yes I did add it but still nothing. Okay, so I have a program with a menu and at the menu choice it keeps coming up with syntax error at the "**:**" colon, help please I have tried everything. 
Here's the code :

```
def main():
    print("Hello and Welcome to the 'Say When' program")

    print("1:Class\n2:Priamry\n3:Secondary\n4:FirstGag\n5:SecondGag")
    menu = (input("What would you like to search?: ")
            if menu == '1':
                print("You chose Class")
                list = ['Assault', 'Engineer', 'Support', 'Recon']
                from random import choice
                print(choice(list))

            elif menu == '2'
                print("nice")
```

Error = *Syntax error* then it highlights the "**:**" in red.

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong, why is the `if` indented more than the previous line?

Comment: You have an extra ( before input. Also, are you using Pythong 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: There are many things wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses on your `input` function, which you don't need at all.

```
menu = input("What would you like to search?: ")
```

Full fixed code:

```
def main():
    print("Hello and Welcome to the 'Say When' program")

    print("1:Class\n2:Priamry\n3:Secondary\n4:FirstGag\n5:SecondGag")
    menu = input("What would you like to search?: ")
    if menu == '1':
        print("You chose Class")
        list = ['Assault', 'Engineer', 'Support', 'Recon']
        from random import choice
        print(choice(list))

    elif menu == '2':
        print("nice")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `input()` has an unnecessary paranthesis in the beginning.
2. The `if` statement is wrongly indented more.
3. The `elif` doesn't have a `:`
4. Imports must be made at the beginning.

Correct code

```
from random import choice
def main():
    print("Hello and Welcome to the 'Say When' program")

    print("1:Class\n2:Priamry\n3:Secondary\n4:FirstGag\n5:SecondGag")
    menu = input("What would you like to search?: ")
    if menu == '1':
        print("You chose Class")
        list = ['Assault', 'Engineer', 'Support', 'Recon']
        print(choice(list))

    elif menu == '2':
        print("nice")
```